# Access included table properties in entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two tables:

Table 1 (Sale):

```
Id   |    CustomerId
```

Table 2 (SaleProduct):

```
Id   |    SaleId |     Quantity
```

I have the following statement:

```
var topSales = db.Sales.Include(c => c.SaleProducts).Where(p =>p.CustomerId == id);
```

I want to sort the SaleProducts table, and select 5 top(ordered by quantity) based on SaleId foreign key, where CustomerId is equal with an id it receives in a controller method.
How can I access the SaleProducts properties in order to do something like this:

```
var orderedItems = topSales.OrderByDescending(c => c.Quantity).Take(5);
```

When I include the SaleProducts table I have in there all the properties but I can't accesc them like in the statement above.
**Any help is appreciated**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options here:

### First option.

Try querying `SaleProduct` table instead of `Sale` table and `Include` `Sale`:

```
var topSaleProducts = db.SaleProducts
    .Where(m => m.Sale.CustomerId == id)
    .Include(m => m.Sale)
    .OrderByDescending(m => m.Quantity)
    .Take(5);
```

Now you have *top 5* sale products according to `CustomerId` and `Sale` will alse be loaded.

### Second option.

You can use explicit loading to get top 5 SaleProducts after loading `Sale`. Remember that, you will query database twice by this way:

```
// Load the sale first
var topSale = db.Sales.First(m => m.CustomerId == id);

// Then load SaleProducts using Explicit loading.
db.Entry(topSale)
    .Collection(m => m.SaleProducts)
    .Query()
    .OrderByDescending(m => m.Quantity)
    .Take(5)
    .Load();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can order by when you access the SaleProducts property and use `Take` method to get 5 items.

```
var prods2 = db.Sales.Include(c => c.SaleProducts)
               .Where(p =>p.CustomerId == id)
               .Select(g => new
                         {
                           SaleId = g.Id,
                           Products = g.SaleProducts.OrderByDescending(h => h.Quantity)
                                       .Take(5)
                                       .Select(x => new
                                                        {
                                                          Id = x.Id,
                                                          Quantity = x.Quantity

                                                         })
                        }).ToList();
```

The above code will give you the Sales for a specific customer and for each customer it will include only the top 5 SaleProduct's (sorted by quantity)

I am projecting the results to an anonymous object ( `new { }`). If you have a view model, you can change the projection to that.

```
public class SaleVm
    {
        public int Id { set; get; }
        public int CustomerId { set; get; }
        public List<SaleProductVm> SaleProducts { set; get; }
}

public class SaleProductVm
{
        public int Id { set; get; }
        public int SaleId { set; get; }
        public int Quantity { set; get; }
}
```

Simply replace the annonymous object projection with these classes

```
List<SaleVm> prods2 = db.Sales.Include(c => c.SaleProducts)
                        .Where(p =>p.CustomerId == id)
                        .Select(g => new SaleVm
                         {
                           SaleId = g.Id,
                           Products = g.SaleProducts.OrderByDescending(h => h.Quantity)
                                       .Take(5)
                                       .Select(x => new SaleProductVm
                                                        {
                                                          Id = x.Id,
                                                          Quantity = x.Quantity  
                                                         })
                        }).ToList();
```

Comment: I think, OP does not asked to get Quantities which are greater than 5, there can be 100 `SaleProducts` which have quantity more than 5. He wants to load top 5 of them

Comment: @Adil Mammadov: You are right, I want top 5 products ordered by quantity, after I've selected a specific customer